# how do i link to static library with this makefile?

Tags: makefile, static, ld, lib

I am using Ubuntu 18. I have a static library that I created:
/path-to-lib/myLib.a

I have a project that I want to compile, linking to this library. Here is the makefile I am trying to use:

```
CC             = g++
STANDARD_FLAGS = -std=c++11\
         -pedantic-errors\
         -Wall\
         -Wextra\
         -Werror\
         -Wconversion\
         -L/home/maxx/projects/Deck\
         -llibStandardDeck

DEBUG_FLAGS = -g3
OPT_FLAGS   = -O0
CCFLAGS     = $(OPT_FLAGS) $(DEBUG_FLAGS) $(STANDARD_FLAGS)
LDFLAGS     =

ROOT     = $(CURDIR)
INCLUDES = -I$(ROOT)/src -I$(ROOT)/api

SRCS = ./src/obj0.cc\
   ./src/obj1.cc\
   ./src/obj2.cc\
   ./src/main.cc

OBJS = ./build/obj0.o\
   ./build/obj1.o\
   ./build/obj2.o\
   ./build/main.o

VPATH    = src
BUILDDIR = build

LIBS = 
MAIN = main

all:    $(MAIN)
    @echo $(MAIN) has been compiled!

$(MAIN): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(MAIN) 

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: %.cc
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@

depend: $(SRCS)
    makedepend $(INCLUDES) $^

clean:
    rm -r $(BUILDDIR) $(MAIN)
```

I am getting the:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmyLib
```

Not sure what to try from here, maybe something in my makefile is wrong?

Comment: Do you know how to link to the library on the command line (that is, *without* Make)?

Comment: I thought I did, I have tried something simple:
    `g++ -L/path-to-lib -lmyLib main.cc -o main`. But this does not work, thought this was one way to do it. This is when main is not referencing any other headers other than what is part of myLib

Comment: just realized, my lib was called, libMyLib.so, something like that. when using `-l<libname>` i guess it searches for `lib<name>` when it is a .so, so i should have put `-lMyLib`. Now it sees it and I am onto new problems, lets see where this goes...

Comment: Just the push I needed, I should have thought to just step back and keep it simple. Thank you Beta!!!